# C# Transform Data in ETL Process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, etl

I am learning the ETL process in C# and have already extracted and read the sample CSV data but am unsure at what to do to **transform** it properly.

I have been using [this website](http://etldatabase.com/etl-transform/) as a reference at how to transform data, but I am unsure on how to *apply* it to my sample data (below).

> name,gender,age,numKids,hasPet,petType
>
> Carl,M,43,2,true,gecko
>
> Jake,M,22,1,true,snake
>
> Cindy,F,53,3,false,null
>
> Matt,M,23,0,true,dog
>
> Ally,F,28,1,false,null
>
> Megan,F,42,2,false,null
>
> Carly,F,34,4,true,cat
>
> Neal,M,27,2,false,null
>
> Tina,F,21,2,true,pig
>
> Paul,M,1,3,true,chicken

Below is how I extracted the data from the CSV file using [CSVHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#reading-reading-individual-fields)

```
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Users\Grant\Documents\SampleData4.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            CsvConfiguration csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration()
            {BufferSize = bufferSize, AllowComments = true};

            using (var csv = new CsvReader(sr, csvConfig))
            {
                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    var name = csv.GetField<string>(0);
                    var gender = csv.GetField<string>(1);
                    var age = csv.GetField<int>(2);
                    var numKids = csv.GetField<int>(3);
                    var hasPet = csv.GetField<bool>(4);
                    var petType = csv.GetField<string>(5);
                }
            }
        }
```

If you need me to provide additional details, just ask below.

Comment: what you need to do is look up how to use the `Split()` function and split the comma ,you can easily read and store the contents of this file into a Class to work from.. do a google search on Reading CSV files in C# tons of excellent working examples online..

Comment: We need more context... how are you pulling the data, what do you want the transformed data to look like, where are you sending it?

Comment: Extract: Load CSV file, transform to your target DB scheme, load the transformed values.
This is something you have to figure out. Is the sample sufficiently transformed to fit in your destination DB?

Comment: @MethodMan Don't use `Split()` for CSV data. It's relatively slow, and there are many edge cases where it doesn't work. Get a dedicated csv parser.

Comment: @MethodMan - I have already read and extracted the data from the CSV but I don't know what to do to transform the data.

Comment: @GrantMeehan how are you handling the extracted data? Pull to CSV is only part of the extraction. We also need to know how you access it in your program. And once we know that, we need to know what you want to transform it into.

Comment: @GrantMeehan That already looks quite well. Which info do you need in your DB?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn -  I don't know how to apply the transformations to this data because it seems like this data is too simple to transform. There doesn't seem like there is anything to transform. Do you think I need different data that has more of a purpose?

Comment: Well, for one you don't need hasPet if you have a pet field, simply do a null reference check and you have your bool

Comment: You use a Transform step when the target schema does not match the source schema. For example, your source data has an `age` field. You need a Transform step if your target for the load uses a `BirthDate` field instead, and you need to calculate that based on the age. If the Target and Source match up exactly, there is no Transform step. Or, for example, the target might not even have a `hasPet` field, instead relying on anything other than `null` in the `petType` column to determine that information.

Comment: @GrantMeehan When I was learning BI we had to transform economical infos from http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/data/database. Some tables there are quite complex and we only needed a few columns of each table. So you can surely use them to create something. You country most likely has something similar.

Comment: So if I wanted their `birthYear` instead of wanting their `age`, then I would use a transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Although a little late, I still would like to add an answer:

To create you own ETL process and Data Flow with C#, I would recommend you the nuget package ETLBox (https://etlbox.net). It will enable you to write a ETL data flow, where the CSV reader implementation is already wrapped in a `CSVSource` object. E.g., you would have to do the following to load data from a CSV into a database:

Defina a CSV source

```
CSVSource sourceOrderData = new CSVSource("demodata.csv");
```

Optionally define a row transformation:

```
RowTransformation<string[], Order> rowTrans = new RowTransformation<string[], Order>(
  row => new Order(row)
);
```

Define the destination

```
DBDestination<Order> dest = new DBDestination<Order>("dbo.OrderTable");
```

Link your ETL data pipeline together

```
sourceOrderData.LinkTo(rowTrans);
rowTrans.LinkTo(dest);
```

Finally start the dataflow (async) and wait for all data to be loaded.

```
source.Execute();
dest.Wait();
```